# Solving a second order matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

How to solve 
$$x''+2Ax'+A^2x=0$$
where $A$ is a constant matrix and $x$ is a vector ?
I assumed the form was $x=c\cdot \exp(At)$ similar to how it does done for normal second order equations.
I got the characteristic equation as $t^2+2At+A^2=0$
with the double root $t=-A$
then I wrote the final solution as:

$$y=c1\cdot\exp(-At)+c2 \cdot t \cdot \exp(-At)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a post that can help with Mathjax.

Comment: Please use mathjax for your next posts.